# Property decorator for getter and setter

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators

I am a bit confused about how to get and set temperature in this property decorated code. Is this the right way to use the property decorator? However I am not sure how to use it. I can call c.temperature and it returns the initial value (0 or whatever I used to instantiate the class) but after that I am not able to set the temperature using set_temperature(). I looked at a couple of SO answers on this topic but probably missed the point.

```
class Celsius:
  def __init__(self, temperature=0):
    self._temperature = temperature

  def to_f(self):
    return self._temperature * 1.8 + 32

  @property
  def temperature(self):
    print "Celsius:get_temperature"
    return self._temperature

  @temperature.setter
  def temperature(self, value):
    if value < -273:
        raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is impossible")
    print "Celsius:set_temperature"
    self._temperature = value
```

Comment: "but after that I am not able to set the temperature using set_temperature()" - why did you expect there to be anything called `set_temperature`? You never defined anything by that name.

Comment: actually it wasnt working even with just c.temperature = 10 for eg, I think because I wasnt inheriting from object (as noted in the other answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property lets you hook into attribute access, and *setting* the attribute. The setter is called when you assign to the attribute:

```
c = Celsius(20)
c.temperature = 40
```

Note however that in Python 2, you need to inherit from `object` for the property to work:

```
class Celsius(object):
```

Demo:

```
>>> c = Celsius(20)
>>> c.temperature
Celsius:get_temperature
20
>>> c.temperature = 40
Celsius:set_temperature
>>> c.temperature
Celsius:get_temperature
40
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I was using python 2.7 - and not inheriting from object.